# In Azure Devops is there a way to show tooltips or extended alt text for a field in a work item?

Tags: azure-devops

In ADO is there an extension available, or a simple way to show Alt text or a Tooltip for a field in a work item?

For example, in the description field of a user story, I'd like to see a little bubble with an i for information, when i hover over it, or click on it, it would display the ideal data for that field and the formatting that's expected.